# Как записать чар в масив, а потом вернуть этот масив?

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, char

Как можно записать чар в масив (который проходит условие), а потом вернуть этот масив? Хочу вывести масив символом которые встречаются в строке 2 и более раз.например ввожу строку “Hello and hi”, а возвращаю в метод массив char[h,l].

```
static void Main()
        {
            string str1 = "Hello and hi";

            Console.WriteLine(Duplicate(str1)); 

        }
        static char[] Duplicate(string str1)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < str1.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (str1[i] == str1[j])
                    {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Comment: Дубликатов чего именно? Опишите задачу для меня, а не для себя.

Comment: Изменил описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private char[] GetCharArrayLinq(string input)
{
    var groups = input.GroupBy(c => char.ToLower(c)).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToArray();

    var charArray = new char[groups.Count()];

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); i++)
    {
        charArray[i] = groups[i].Key;
    }

    return charArray;
}
```

Comment: `input.GroupBy(c => char.ToLower(c))` => `input.ToLower().GroupBy(c => c)`, так быстрее отработает. Еще `groups.Count()` => `groups.Length`